# error in python palindrome program it says module error

Tags: python

```
str1 = []
x = input("Enter a string : ");
str1.append(x)

def isPalindrome(str1):
    for i in range(0, len(str1)/2):
       if str1[0] != str1[len(str1)-i-1]:
           return False
    return True

ans = isPalindrome(str1)
if(ans):
    print("String is palindrome")
else:
    print("string is not palindrome")
```

Comment: What error? Please add your error.

Comment: `len(str1)/2` inside the `range` function would not work as it is interpreted as float, change it to: `len(str1)//2`

Comment: no eroor but the logic dosen't work even the string is not a palindrome it says it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code:

1. As mentioned, the arguments to a `range` function must be integers so either use floor division (`//`) or wrap a function in `int()`. A float will cause a `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`
2. Also as mentioned, you're appending `x` to a list and then passing the list to `isPalindrome` - you either need to pass x (e.g. str1[0]) or you need a to iterate over str1 and pass the strings to isPalindrome one at a time.
3. To check the characters are palindromic, you can simplify use the fact that [0] is the first item and [-1] is the last - no need to check `len`

```
str1 = []
x = input("Enter a string : ")
str1.append(x)

def isPalindrome(str1):
    for i in range(len(str1)//2):
        # if str1[i] != str1[len(str1)-i-1]:
        if str1[i] != str1[-i -1]:
            return False
    return True

ans = isPalindrome(str1[0])
if ans:
    print("String is palindrome")
else:
    print("string is not palindrome")
```

Finally, just a note that there is a much more Pythonic way than looping over the string, and that is to use the fact that you can reverse a string with `string[::-1]` so you could simplify `isPalindrome` much further to just:

```
def isPalindrome(str1):
    return str1 == str1[::-1]
```

This will return True if it is a palindrome, otherwise False.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sayandip Dutta  mentioned
`len(str1)/2` inside the range function would not work as it is interpreted as float, change it to: `len(str1)//2`

You are passing a list to the `isPalindrome` function, iterate over str1 and pass the strings to the function.
You need to change `if str1[0]` to `if str1[i]`

Answer (score -1):

```
    string=input(("Enter a string:"))
    if(string==string[::-1]):
      print("The string is a palindrome")
    else:
      print("Not a palindrome")
```

[image]

In program, first take input from user (using input) to check for palindrome.Then use slice operation[start:end:step] ,check whether string is reversed or not.Here step value of -1 reverses a string.If yes ,it prints palindrome else not palindrome